# How to make the Fujitsu lifebook T5010 screen rotate?

Tags: tablet

I recently purchased a Fujitsu Lifebook T5010. It came pre-loaded with Linux mint olivia. I had a hard time figuring out how to use Linux mint and installed Ubuntu 13. 04 on my laptop.

Since I installed Ubuntu my Screen has stopped rotating when I turn it into tablet mode. Is there a website that I need to go to download a driver or a program so that the screen will auto-rotate when I switch it to tablet mode?

Comment: I can't test it my self, but this might help you: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=958929&page=2&p=7312857#post7312857

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, all drivers are inside the kernel, so to get new drivers you just download the latest Linux kernel. You can find Ubuntu kernels here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

I highly recommend the latest kernel 3.12-rc7. To install the kernel, you simply download the three debs for your system. If you have a 64-bit system then that would mean downloading *_all.deb and *_amd64.deb and installing them.

#### For 64-bit 3.12-rc7

```
cd ~/tmp
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-rc7-saucy/linux-headers-3.12.0-031200rc7-generic_3.12.0-031200rc7.201310271935_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-rc7-saucy/linux-headers-3.12.0-031200rc7_3.12.0-031200rc7.201310271935_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-rc7-saucy/linux-image-3.12.0-031200rc7-generic_3.12.0-031200rc7.201310271935_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

#### For 32-bit 3.12-rc7

```
cd ~/tmp
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-rc7-saucy/linux-headers-3.12.0-031200rc7-generic_3.12.0-031200rc7.201310271935_i386.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-rc7-saucy/linux-headers-3.12.0-031200rc7_3.12.0-031200rc7.201310271935_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-rc7-saucy/linux-image-3.12.0-031200rc7-generic_3.12.0-031200rc7.201310271935_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```